# I updated my WordPress blog and now a blank screen appears when I sign in

Tags: wordpress

I just updated the latest version of WordPress and now when I sign in – the screen is blank. I can't get to the dashboard.

the url reads [my website]/blog/wp-admin/upgrade.php?_wp_http_referer=%2Fblog%2Fwp-admin%2F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope into your site VIA FTP and try to make some tweaks. the `wp-config.php` has some magic like `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` - this may show if you have an outdated plugin, theme or some kind of sloppy code somewhere.

Did you get a chance to [peek at the White Screen of Death FAQ](https://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors)?

Try doing some of these things:

- rename activated theme folder VIA FTP
- move plugins, one at a time, to a different folder, for just a quick moment and than refresh page to see if that fixes
- restore a previous backup, update your plugins / themes THAN try to update

I really hope it's note a database issue, that could mean more time required to fix.

Comment: Thanks, I clicked on your link, I renamed my plugins folder and then when i tried to sign in it asked me to update my database, which I did – and now it's back! I'm going to backup my site before any updates from now on.

Answer (score 1):

One way to maybe fix the problem would be to disable the plugins you use one by one (delete their directories in the wp-content/plugins folder) and able them one by one to check if one one of them is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please rename the plugins in the folder and try to get dashboard once again. Hope will do it for you.

Thanks and Regards